# Angularjs: input for ng-repeat elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sorry for my language skills, hope you understand all.

I need to make inputs for ng-repeat elements, to pass input data to http post.
For example: i have 4 elements, for all elements i make inputs, and f.e:

```
elem1- input: 1 
elem2- input: 4 
elem3- input: 1 
elem4- input: 2
```

Here is my code:

```
.panel-body.note-link ng-repeat=("meal in mealsList track by $index")
                    a data-toggle="tab" 
                      h4.pull-right.text-muted
                        | {{meal.price}} zł

                    h4.text-success
                        i.fa.fa-close.text-danger<> ng-click="removeMeal($index)" style="cursor: pointer;font-size: 15px;"
                        | {{meal.name}} {{$index}}
                        input.form-control type="number"  ng-model="example"
                        | {{example}}
```

And i dont know, how to pass input data to controller.
Any tips,tricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.module('yourModule').controller('viewController', function($scope) {
  $scope.mealList = [...];
  $scope.example; //The input data will automatically bind to this variable.
});
```

If you want the input to change data within your meal object, then do this:

```
input.form-control type="number"  ng-model="meal.example"
```

And then the property value of the meal object would bind to the input

Comment: So, now, what should i do, when i want  see "example" input of, for example, first meal object?

Comment: attach it to the "meal" object. <input ng-model="meal.example"> then when it render all the meals, every meal would have its own "example" input bound to the "example" property

Answer (score 1):

Repeat through your mealList array and add the inputs.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ptzhL0uL/

**Controller**

```
function Controller1($scope) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.items_saved = false;
  vm.mealList = [{
    price: '2.99',
    name: 'Pizza'
  }, {
    price: '1.99',
    name: 'Chips'
  }, {
    price: '4.99',
    name: 'Beer'
  }];

  vm.addNewItem = addNewItem;
  vm.saveItems = saveItems;

  function addNewItem() {
    vm.mealList.push({});
  }

  function saveItems() {
    vm.items_saved = true;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="ctrl.addNewItem()" class="btn btn-default">Add Item</button>
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.mealList">
  <input type="text" ng-model="item.name">
  <input type="text" ng-model="item.price">
  <input type="number" ng-model="item.quantity">
</div>
<button ng-click="ctrl.saveItems()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
<hr>
<div ng-if="ctrl.items_saved">
  <h4>Here is your meal list:</h4>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.mealList">{{item.quantity}}{{item.name}} at ${{item.price}} each</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just attach it to the `ngModel` directive.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array">
    {{ item.output }}

    <input ng-model="item.output" />
</div>
```